# I want to know how to translate Magento 2 mail templates

Tags: magento2.2, localisation

I am providing English and Japanese in Magento 2 project.

We respond so that customers can inquire about products.

I'd like to make the mail template of that module correspond to Japanese, but it will not be translated.

Please tell me how to resolve.

```
<!--@subject {{trans "Customer Ask For Product Details"}} @-->
<!--@vars {
"var data.product_name":"Product Name",
"var data.1":"Customer Name",
"var data.2":"Customer Email",
"var data.3":"Customer Message"
} @-->
{{trans "Dear"}} {{var data.1}}!<br/>
{{trans "We received your question about Product: %product_name" product_name=$data.product_name}}<br/>
{{trans "We respond to you as fast as possible."}}
```

Comment: I think you should put the locale language of site to Japanese,so that the translation start to working. If you are using a custom them you should also add the Japanese translation csv to your theme.